# Modification of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given a second-order differential equation of the form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}=x_0\beta \,\frac{dz}{dt}\,e^{-\beta z/\gamma} - \gamma \,\frac{dz}{dt}
\end{equation}
where, $ x_{0}, \beta, \gamma $ are constants.
By introducing the function
\begin{equation}
u=e^{-\beta z/\gamma} 
\end{equation}
and substituting it into the equation, how can one achieve the form:
\begin{equation}
u\frac{d^{2}u}{dt^{2}}-\bigg(\frac{du}{dt}\bigg)^{2}+\bigg(\gamma-x_{0}\beta u\bigg)u\frac{du}{dt} = 0?
\end{equation}

Comment: Does $'$ denote differentiation with respect to $t$?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, yes indeed everything is differentiated with respect to $t$

Answer (score 2):

We have the equation $$z''=(x_0\beta u-\gamma)z'\tag1$$
Given that substitution, we can compute $z'$ and $z''$ in terms of derivatives of $u$.
$$z=-\frac\gamma\beta\log u\\z'=-\frac\gamma{\beta u}u'\\z''=\frac\gamma{\beta u^2}(u')^2-\frac\gamma{\beta u}u''$$Substitute these results into $(1)$ and multiply through by $-\frac{\beta u^2}\gamma$ to obtain the desired equation.